# Catch specific string using regex

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I have multiple boards. Inside my bash script, I want to catch my root filesystem name using regex. When I do a `cat /proc/cmdline`, I have this:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-57-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

I just want to select `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`

So far I have managed to catch `root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` using this command

```
\broot=[^ ]+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your regex in `sed` with a capture group:

```bash
sed -E 's~.* root=([^ ]+).*~\1~' /proc/cmdline

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```

Another option is to use `awk`(should work in any `awk`):

```bash
awk 'match($0, /root=[^ ]+/) {
   print substr($0, RSTART+5, RLENGTH-5)
}' /proc/cmdline

# if your string is always 2nd field then a simpler one
awk '{sub(/^[^=]+=/, "", $2); print $2}' /proc/cmdline
```

Comment: since `root=` is already a requirement inside `match(...)`, wouldn't it be simpler to directly `substr(...)` from `RSTART + 5` (and deduct the same from `RLENGTH`) ?

Comment: Thanks, That's a very valid point @RAREKpopManifesto (edited).

Answer (score 6):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+root=[^[:space:]]+' '
RT && split(RT,arr,"="){
  print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `grep` you could try following solution, using `-oP` options to enable PCRE regex in `grep` and in main section of `grep` using regex `^.*?[[:space:]]root=\K\S+` where `\K` is used for forgetting matched values till `root=` and get rest of the values as required.

```bash
grep -oP '^.*?[[:space:]]root=\K\S+' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** In case your Input_file is always same as shown samples then try this Simple `awk` using field separator(s) concept.

```bash
awk -F' |root=' '{print $3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

If the second field has the value, using awk you can split and check for `root`

```
awk '
{
  n=split($2,a,"=")
  if (n==2 && a[1]=="root"){
    print a[2]
  }
}
' file
```

Output

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```

---

***Or*** using `GNU-awk` with a capture group

```
awk 'match($0, /(^|\s)root=(\S+)/, a) {print a[2]}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Linux, you can use a GNU grep:

```bash
grep -oP '\broot=\K\S+'
```

where `o` allows match output, and `P` sets the regex engine to PCRE. See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VeXmvS). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `root=` - a fixed string
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` solution, using good ole' `FS / OFS` :

*-- no PCRE, capture groups, `match()`, `g/sub()`, or `substr()` needed*

```
echo 'BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-57-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='^[^=]+=[^=]+=| [^/]+$' OFS=
> ```

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```

if you're ***very very*** certain the structure has `root=`, then :

> ```
> gawk NF=NF FS='^.+root=| .+$' OFS=
> ```

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```

if you like doing it the `RS` way instead :

> ```
> nawk '$!NF = $NF' FS== RS=' [^/]+\n'
> ```

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```